# How can generate one record into two records and then insert them into the table?

Tags: sql-server

I have PKT table in sql server with structure(PKT(pso, day, msch, mskh, tkc, tkdu, st, mskh1)) and an other table(dong_bo(pso, day, msch, mskh, tk, psn, psc)).
With each row in PKT, i need to generate it to two rows then insert them into dong_bo table.
For Example: PKT table.
| pso | day | msch | mskh | tkc | tkdu | st | mskh1 |
| --- | --- | ---- | ---- | --- | ---- | -- | ----- |
| PKHT000105-12-20 | 31/12/2020 | 03 | 0802345 | C1411 | N3311 | 20000 | 7101259|

#### dong_bo table:

| pso | day | msch | mskh | tk | psn | psc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PKHT000105-12-20 | 31/12/2020 | 03 | 0802345 | 1411 | 0 | 20000 |
| PKHT000105-12-20 | 31/12/2020 | 03 | 7101259 | 3311 | 20000 | 0 |

I need a statement to generate it in SQL server.

Comment: Your question is too broad and vague to be actionable. You should consider adding more context and interface details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use `union all` statement as approach:

```
insert into dong_bo
select pso, day, mskh, right(tkc, 4) tkc, 0 psn, st psc from PKT
union all
select pso, day, mskh1, right(tkdu, 4) tkc, st psn, 0 psc from PKT;
```

Check this [SQL online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b321a978cec8e6b03a1a0bb801a2ea22&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

Result:

```
+==================+============+=========+======+=======+=======+
| pso              | day        | mskh    | tkc  | psn   | psc   |
+==================+============+=========+======+=======+=======+
| PKHT000105-12-20 | 31/12/2020 | 0802345 | 1411 | 0     | 20000 |
+------------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| PKHT000105-12-20 | 31/12/2020 | 7101259 | 3311 | 20000 | 0     |
+------------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-------+
```